# How to calculate the derivate of a function for a set variable?

Tags: matlab

Let's say I input following sentences:

```
x = 5
y = x.^2
z = diff(y)
```

But I'll be getting

```
z =

     []
```

as result, while I'd like to get the actual value of `2x` as result, that is `10`.

I know the existance of `syms` and I've tried adding it for `x` and `y` values but got not results.

Comment: `y` here is just a number, not a function.

Comment: There's a reason why I am asking, maybe it's too simple but if you've got a hint, you can always offer an asnwer, @herohuyongtao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use symbolic expression:

```
syms x y            % creates symbolic variables x,y
y = x^2;            % symbolic expression
t = diff(y);        % t = 2*x (differentiate symbolic expression of y)
z = subs(t, x, 5)   % evaluate t, i.e. z=2*5=10
```